# smoothScrollToPosition is inconsistent. How to fix?

Tags: android, smooth-scrolling, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView populated with a fixed amount of items. There are 4 rows that are designated as section headers and use a different layout. I'm trying to implement a "jump-to" for each section, but smoothScrollToPosition doesn't go to the right row, or even line up consistently on the wrong row.

Has anyone had any problems similar to this? I can post some of my code, but it's all rather basic. So before I do that, I thought I'd just ask in words.

Comment: As an additional note. "smoothScrollToPosition" works the same inconsistent wrong way with a ListView as it does with RecyclerView. "setSelection" however, works as expected.